# PL/SQL : Apply condition only for INSERTING and not for UPDATING

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My requirement is to insert into a table only when `COLUMN1 IS NULL`.
I have the below code.
But, the problem here is, the update will not happen if `COLUMN1 is NOT NULL`.
I want the update to happen even if `COLUMN1 IS NULL`.

How to apply the NULL condition check only for insert and not for update?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON MYTABLE1
FOR EACH ROW
when (NEW.COLUMN1 IS NULL)
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2(COLUMN2) VALUES (:NEW.COLUMN1);
 ELSIF UPDATING THEN
UPDATE MYTABLE2 SET COLUMNX = :NEW.COLUMNX;
END IF;
END MYTRIGGER;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON MYTABLE1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSERTING AND (:NEW.COLUMN1 IS NULL) THEN
INSERT INTO MYTABLE2(COLUMN2) VALUES (:NEW.COLUMN1);
 ELSIF UPDATING THEN
UPDATE MYTABLE2 SET COLUMNX = :NEW.COLUMNX;
END IF;
END MYTRIGGER;
```

Or you can create 2 different triggers for insert and update.

Comment: It gives syntax error when I compile ..`PLS-00201:identifier NEW.COLUMN1 must be declared.`

Comment: @user2488578 Try now.